# many entities one table hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I work with mySQL, hibernate and Spring Datas and I want to link a table with more than one entity.

The table looks like this but more complex (with many-to-one relations...) :

```
CREATE TABLE FOOBAR (
    id BIGINTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type ENUM('FOO', 'BAR'),
    name VARCHAR(30),
    foo_style ENUM('ONE', 'TWO')),
    PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

The entities that I want to create. I want a generic table that cans recover all the entries, and two tables that cans recover only the rows corresponding to the correct enum :

```
@Table
public class FooBar {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FooStyle fooStyle;
}

@Table //On type foo
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FooStyle fooStyle;
}

@Table //On type bar
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: That looks like a terrible idea. If the table contains several kinds of things, then you should have one table for each kind. If the table contains a single kind of things, then you should have a single entity, or possibly an entity and several sub-entities, using inheritance and the SINGLE_TABLE inheritace strategy. This is of course covered in the user manual. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Comment: @Tony can you please tell us what is the need of Bar Entity..It seems you have defined but not using..

Comment: This is an example. In fact, I have Person entities and, I need all of the informations into it. And I need some classes that are types of Person. I need the entities, and for performance reason, I can't use DTOs. But I don't want to have redundancy in my database by creation of multiple tables...